# Does it mean that Memory usage of app same as size of app

Tags: applications

This is a conceptual doubt I have. Request some one to resolve my doubt. I have an app of size of 4.5MB and I am calculating memory usage of processes in the app. I am getting each process memory usage as 16MB...

final Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
rt.gc();
final double startSize = rt.totalMemory()-rt.freeMemory();

What I am getting is correct or wrong?Does it mean that Memory usage of app same is same as size of app?

Comment: are you sure that by "memory usage" you mean RAM usage? It's easy to mix the two up.

Comment: I saw that  Runtime.getRuntime() is going to give me memory in VM

Comment: What was that outputting?

Comment: Yeah as i said - final double startSize = rt.totalMemory()-rt.freeMemory() was outputting 16MB for each process

Comment: good point. Hmmm, it could be cache and app data. The app itself may be 4.5mb, but what about everything else it has?

Comment: The cache is 20KB and app data is 16 KB.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30428/discussion-between-dan-b-and-materazzi06).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It is correct, there is no reason for the memory usage of you app to be the same size as the apk.

Comment: Actually, there's no reason the two are related at all: A small app can eat a lot of RAM, as well as a large app can be well optimized (or just have parts of itself running).